# Why nanosleep() adds a constant delay and how can I avoid that?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, real-time

I would like to drive a stepper motor with my RaspberryPi 3. I need to generate about 10000 pulses a second, which means I need to generate pulses with ~100us intervals. I know Raspberry can generate PWM, but this is not the case as I need precisely control number of pulses as well as acceleration/decceleration, so I would prefer an explicit loop.

Although busy looping gives pretty precise timings, it obviously consumes 100% CPU time. At the same time nanosleep() provide pretty good balance between time precision and CPU load - I can drive the motor with just about 10% CPU load.

BUT. I wrote a small piece of code to measure nanosleep() delays

```
    unsigned long iterations = 5000;
    for(int d=10; d<500; d+=5)
    {
        unsigned long accumDelayTime = 0;
        unsigned long accumExpDelayTime = 0;
        for(unsigned long i=0; i<iterations; i++)
        {
            accumExpDelayTime += d;

            unsigned long start = micros();
            struct timespec ts;
            ts.tv_sec = 0;
            ts.tv_nsec = 1000*d;
            clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, &ts, NULL);

            unsigned long end = micros();

            accumDelayTime += end - start;
        }

        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", accumExpDelayTime / iterations, accumDelayTime / iterations, (accumDelayTime - accumExpDelayTime) / iterations);
    }
```

I totally understand that generic linux (and particularly Raspbian) is not a RTOS, there are other processes that share same CPU resources with my program - I am pretty ok with that. I am ok if my app will get a little slower if there is other CPU consuming process.

But results were pretty surprising. Columns are: requested delay, actual delay, difference between requested and actual delay

```
10      80      70
15      85      70
20      89      69
25      95      70
30      99      69
35      105     70
40      110     70
45      114     69
50      123     70
55      124     69
60      129     69
65      134     69
70      130     60    <---- here I run CPU-heavy process
75      135     60
80      140     60
85      145     60
90      150     60
95      158     62
100     161     61
105     166     61
110     172     62
115     177     62
120     181     61
125     186     61
130     191     61
135     205     70    <---- here it finished
140     210     70
145     215     70
150     220     70
155     225     70
160     230     70
165     235     70
```

I tried nanosleep(), clock_nanosleep(), and usleep() - result is pretty much the same.

I have few quesions on these results:
1) Why do I have a difference between desired sleep time and actual?
2) This difference is pretty stable and does not depend on requested delay. Does anybody have explanation for this?
3) Why this difference gets lower if CPU load increases (I would expect pretty much opposite)?

Answer (score 1):

Your process is running from userspace. In order to both sleep and get the time, you need to switch to kernel space. This incurs an overhead. Also any sleep function only guarantees wakeup sometime after the sleep timer has expired.

Bottom line, in order to attempt to get the precision you desire, you probably will need to write your code as a device driver. This gives you direct access to the high resolution timers that you desire.

Comment: Yes, I am considering writing a kernel module, but this will require some time to learn how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> **1) Why do I have a difference between desired sleep time and actual?**

[Excerpt from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_(system_call)):

> While there is generally a guarantee for the minimum time period, there is no strict guarantee that the thread will run immediately or soon, or even at all, once the specified time has passed. It is up to the scheduler's discretion, and dependent on thread priorities and implementation details such as timer resolutions when the sleeping thread will run again.

This applies to Linux too. If your process is critical, you can increase it's priority using [`nice`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nice) command, which will affect process scheduling and *might* give you better results.

> **2) This difference is pretty stable and does not depend on requested delay. Does anybody have explanation for this?**

Apart from what is mentioned above, another factor is [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch). Excerpt from Wikipedia:

> In computing, a context switch is the process of storing the state of a process or of a thread, so that it can be restored and execution resumed from the same point later. This allows multiple processes to share a single CPU, and is an essential feature of a multitasking operating system.

Obviously, context switch takes time, and that's what should be considered in your tests.

> **3) Why this difference gets lower if CPU load increases (I would expect pretty much opposite)?**

There are [few governors in Linux kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt), and default one is `ondemand`. Excerpt from kernel documentation:

> The CPUfreq governor "ondemand" sets the CPU frequency depending on the
>   current system load.

This means your system *might* get more responsive if there's a bigger CPU load.

For your tests you might want to set the governor to `performance` or `userspace` to get results not influenced by dynamically changing CPU speeds:

```
echo performance > /sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
echo 1000000 > /sys/bus/cpu/devices/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

Comment: Thanks, switching to 'performance' mode made delay more stable. It no longer depends on CPU load, but it is still about 60us.

Comment: Added answers for 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the timer latency (i.e., the difference between desired sleep time and actual) is caused by a kernel parameter called *timer_slop*. Its default value is 50 us, which means your timer would be delayed at maximum 50 us. *timer_slop* is desinged to improve system performance by batching timer interrupts and thus reducing the number of timer interrupts. https://lwn.net/Articles/262493/

You could change a process' *timer_slop* via file /proc/[pid]/timerslack_ns. 
For example, the command `echo 10000 > /proc/[pid]/timerslack_ns` changes timer_slop to 10 us.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Why do I have a difference between desired sleep time and actual?

Linux probably waits until the desired time has elapsed, then takes a certain amount of time to switch back to your task and return from kernel.

> 3) Why this difference gets lower if CPU load increases (I would expect pretty much opposite)?

It's likely that when the CPU has nothing to do (e.g. because you're "nano-delaying") Linux puts the CPU into some kind of sleep state to reduce power consumption; and when your delay expires it takes extra time to wake the CPU up. Of course if there's other work for the CPU to do it won't be put into a sleep state (and won't save power) and won't need to be woken up either.

Note that you'd probably have more fun using TIMER_ABSTIME to ensure that the extra latency is constant (and doesn't increase - e.g. 65 microseconds late this time, 130 microseconds late next time, 196 microseconds late the time after that, ...).